# Get the measured length from profile image

Tags: dm-script

I'd like to get the measured length from profile image. At first, I thought it's something like a component. But TagGroupCountTags showed that it's not a component. The information about profile image is very little in the document. Hope someone could give me some idea what's the type of this measurement.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this part of the display is not accessible in any form, unfortunately. (But the values can of course be easily calculated form the ROI's range in channel and the image calibration.)

Comment: ROIGetRange works. Thanks for your hint